# Optimize MYSQL query with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, performance

i have one simple query, but on the other hand relatively big table.
Here it is:

```
select `stats_ad_groups`.`ad_group_id`, 
    sum(stats_ad_groups.earned) / 1000000  as earned 
from `stats_ad_groups` 
    where `stats_ad_groups`.`day` between '2018-01-01' and '2018-05-31' 
group by `ad_group_id` order by earned asc
limit 10
```

And here is table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats_ad_groups` (
  `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ad_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`impressions` int(11) NOT NULL,
`clicks` int(11) NOT NULL,
`avg_position` double(3,1) NOT NULL,
`cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
`profiles` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`upgrades` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`earned` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`day` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ad_group_id`,`day`,`campaign_id`)
)
```

Also there are partitions by range here, but i excluded them, not to waste space :)

Query I wrote here is executed in about 9 sec. Do you know some way to improve it? 
If i exclude limit/order by its executed in 200ms.

To sum it:
I need to order by sum on big table, if its possible with limit and offset.

Comment: What does the EXPLAIN say?

Comment: And what happens if you make day the first column in the pk?

Comment: As @Strawberry suggested, try changing PK order to: `PRIMARY KEY (day, ad_group_id,campaign_id)`

Comment: hey @Strawberry,
i cant change order because i have other queries that are depending on ad_group_id.

Here is EXPLAIN:
`explain select `stats_ad_groups`.`ad_group_id`,
sum(stats_ad_groups.earned) / 1000000  as earned 
from `stats_ad_groups`
where `stats_ad_groups`.`day` between '2018-04-01' and '2018-12-31' 
group by `ad_group_id`  

SIMPLE stats_ad_groups index NULL PRIMARY 11 NULL 62267742 Using where
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INDEX(day, ad_group_id, earned)
```

handles the `WHERE` and is 'covering'.

Is your PARTITIONing `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYs(day))` with daily partitions?  If so, could leave off `day` from that index.

With that index, `PARTITIONing` provides no extra performance for *this* query.

For significant speedup, build and maintain a summary table that has day, ad_group_id, SUM(earned).  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Don't use `(m,n)` on `DOUBLE` or `FLOAT`.

Comment: Thank you Rick . This makes sense! I'll have to create new summary tables, its only logical solution. I tried with catching, but there are so may cases I should cover that cache grows over 30gb. LOL :)

I have one question for you.
I can sort with multiple columns, for example sum(earned), sum(cost), sum(clicks), and few more.
What do you think, should i create separate tables for each of them, or use one table and add primary key [day, ad_group_id] and use index on these fields (I think this way it will be pretty slow for updating ).

And partitions are by months

Comment: here it is `PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`day`)) (PARTITION `p_2017_july` VALUES LESS THAN (736907) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION `p_2017_august` VALUES LESS THAN (736938) ENGINE = InnoDB`

Comment: @BrankoDragovic - The summary table should have a fraction of the number of rows, hence the 'reporting' query will take a fraction of the time.  Tentatively, that PK is the only index you will need.  And, yes, have subtotals for each of those as the other columns.  Suggest adding `COUNT(*)`, too.

Comment: @BrankoDragovic - also...  I added `earned` to the index to make it "covering".  Don't bother with that for the summary table, especially if the PK suffices for the index to use.